# Make a view pop up always on top

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm relatively new to Xcode and inheriting a project that has a main view and a series of secondary views, some shown and dismissed via buttons and such, and also a set of HUD alerts that need to pop up on top of everything, no matter which of the other screens is shown.  What we're finding is that sometimes our HUD pops up *underneath* a secondary view.  For example our secondary "data" view is popped up like this:

```
myViewControllerLog = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerEmailData"];
[self presentViewController:myViewControllerLog animated:YES completion:nil];
myViewControllerLog.ActivityLogDelegate = self;
```

And we used a third-party HUD component, which is invoked as follows:

```
[MBHUDView hudWithBody:message type:MBAlertViewHUDTypeDefault 
hidesAfter:k_POPUP_DISPLAY_TIME_SECONDS show:YES preferredFontSize:23 wordwrap:YES 
dismiss_current:YES];
```

And inside this construction the HUD calls (which confuses me a little):

```
[self addToWindow];
```

The bad part is that *sometimes* (after a few cycles of use, usually) the HUD ends up showing up underneath the displayed secondary view (we know this because it won't appear when its supposed to, but if we dismiss the secondary view we see it below it).  I don't know if this is a shoddy third party HUD or if we're doing something wrong, but if (a) someone could give me their opinions on the problem which I'm sure I would find educational and (b) is there a way to instantiate/show these views which will ENSURE one of them (the HUD) is always on top?

Thanks very much for any thoughts.

Comment: Not sure but can you check that view which overlap HUD is also not added on window as subview. It might be possible that secondary view added on window and that process done after HUD added to window.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
yourview.layer.zPosition = 10;
```